# Wildfly 8 and Spring Security authentication issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, wildfly-8

I am facing a weird issue on my application where login authentication works fine on Wildfly 9 or 10 versions but have issues on Wildfly 8. On Wildfly 8 after the user authentication fails it throws an exception but on Wildfly 9 or 10 it authenticates and return back with the error message. How this issue can be fix on Wildly 8 or is there any patch or configuration need to be added? I am using Spring MVC and Spring Security.

Below is the excepion on Wildfly 8 after it failed to validate the user:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.AccountDataImporterWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 ]]
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:116)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:99)
at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:90)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:44)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider$ContextFactory.createContext(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:401) [spring-security-ldap-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:202) [spring-security-ldap-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
... 52 more
Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 ]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3135) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2883) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2797) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:114)
... 62 more
```

Code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = 
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("", "");

        authenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        authenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        return authenticationProvider;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details so we can help. Show us your configured/classes that are relevant etc.,

Comment: The exception looks like the intial context is not intialized which is nothing to do with the authentication.

Comment: But i am not getting this exception on wildfly 9 or higher version. When I tried to enter wrong password it validates and return back with the message as "invalid user" but on wildfly 8 it throws an exception. So I am wondering if I need some extra configuration or any external jar need to be added on my wildfly 8 server as this issue do not exist on higher versions?

Comment: I believe Wildfly 8 is not able to lookup initial context for some reason. Please compare the configurations and see.

Comment: Please provide server start up logs, configuration of the spring security.

Comment: Is there a way i can attach my server log file here? Or Do i just have to copy paste my server log content here?

Comment: This is a known bug  for wildfly 8 for spring security login, I am just trying to find a handle to make it work.. Is there any solution or work around?

Comment: Any suggestion or help on my issue?